# Incorrect order with Kahn's algorithm

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, topological-sort

I'm trying to implement the topological ordering with Kahn's algorithm:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def ordering(graph:dict):
    in_counts = defaultdict(int)
    for k, v in graph.items():
        if not k in in_counts:
            in_counts[k] = 0
        for in_node in v:
            in_counts[in_node] += 1

    queue = []
    for in_node in in_counts.keys():
        if in_counts[in_node] == 0:
            queue.append(in_node)

    topological_order = []

    while queue:
        print("in_counts:", in_counts)
        print("queue:", queue)
        current_node = queue.pop(0)
        topological_order.append(current_node)
        print("result:", topological_order)
        if not current_node in graph:
            continue
        for in_node in graph[current_node]:
            in_counts[in_node] -= 1
            if in_counts[in_node] == 0:
                queue.append(in_node)

    return topological_order

print(ordering({'GTTGA': ['CTGAG'], 'TTCAC': ['GTTGA'], 'AAGGC': ['GTTGA', 'TAACA', 'TTCAC'], 'CGGGC': ['GTTGA', 'TAACA'], 'CCCTC': ['GTTGA', 'TAACA', 'TTCAC', 'AAGGC', 'CGGGC', 'CTGAG'], 'AGCTT': ['GTTGA']}))
```

The debug output:

```
in_counts: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'GTTGA': 5, 'CTGAG': 2, 'TTCAC': 2, 'AAGGC': 1, 'TAACA': 3, 'CGGGC': 1, 'CCCTC': 0, 'AGCTT': 0})
queue: ['CCCTC', 'AGCTT']
result: ['CCCTC']
in_counts: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'GTTGA': 4, 'CTGAG': 1, 'TTCAC': 1, 'AAGGC': 0, 'TAACA': 2, 'CGGGC': 0, 'CCCTC': 0, 'AGCTT': 0})
queue: ['AGCTT', 'AAGGC', 'CGGGC']
result: ['CCCTC', 'AGCTT']
in_counts: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'GTTGA': 3, 'CTGAG': 1, 'TTCAC': 1, 'AAGGC': 0, 'TAACA': 2, 'CGGGC': 0, 'CCCTC': 0, 'AGCTT': 0})
queue: ['AAGGC', 'CGGGC']
result: ['CCCTC', 'AGCTT', 'AAGGC']
in_counts: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'GTTGA': 2, 'CTGAG': 1, 'TTCAC': 0, 'AAGGC': 0, 'TAACA': 1, 'CGGGC': 0, 'CCCTC': 0, 'AGCTT': 0})
queue: ['CGGGC', 'TTCAC']
result: ['CCCTC', 'AGCTT', 'AAGGC', 'CGGGC']
in_counts: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'GTTGA': 1, 'CTGAG': 1, 'TTCAC': 0, 'AAGGC': 0, 'TAACA': 0, 'CGGGC': 0, 'CCCTC': 0, 'AGCTT': 0})
queue: ['TTCAC', 'TAACA']
result: ['CCCTC', 'AGCTT', 'AAGGC', 'CGGGC', 'TTCAC']
in_counts: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'GTTGA': 0, 'CTGAG': 1, 'TTCAC': 0, 'AAGGC': 0, 'TAACA': 0, 'CGGGC': 0, 'CCCTC': 0, 'AGCTT': 0})
queue: ['TAACA', 'GTTGA']
result: ['CCCTC', 'AGCTT', 'AAGGC', 'CGGGC', 'TTCAC', 'TAACA']
in_counts: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'GTTGA': 0, 'CTGAG': 1, 'TTCAC': 0, 'AAGGC': 0, 'TAACA': 0, 'CGGGC': 0, 'CCCTC': 0, 'AGCTT': 0})
queue: ['GTTGA']
result: ['CCCTC', 'AGCTT', 'AAGGC', 'CGGGC', 'TTCAC', 'TAACA', 'GTTGA']
in_counts: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'GTTGA': 0, 'CTGAG': 0, 'TTCAC': 0, 'AAGGC': 0, 'TAACA': 0, 'CGGGC': 0, 'CCCTC': 0, 'AGCTT': 0})
queue: ['CTGAG']
result: ['CCCTC', 'AGCTT', 'AAGGC', 'CGGGC', 'TTCAC', 'TAACA', 'GTTGA', 'CTGAG']
```

The expected result is:

```
['CCCTC', 'CGGGC', 'AGCTT', 'AAGGC', 'TAACA', 'TTCAC', 'GTTGA', 'CTGAG']
```

which is different from my result(see above).

I understand that `CGGGC` should be placed right after `CCCTC`, however I don't understand how this would be not conflicting with the algorithm: at the start both `CCCTC` and `AGCTT` have the in-degree of `0`, and `CGGGC` gets on the queue after `AGCTT`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I did not read your example in length, but just to be sure: are you conscious that the topological sorting of vertices of a graph is not unique, and that therefore your algorithm might give a good answer despite being different ?

Comment: @m.raynal this makes sense, however, I fail to see what can make my answer match the expected one. I suspect there's a preferred choice at every step which I don't see.

Comment: The order will depend on the behavior of your queue (the order in which it pops elements). I see two ways to make sure your algorithm indeed performs well. You could write a program that tests wether your output is indeed a valid topologic sort, or implement [Coffman-Graham algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffman%E2%80%93Graham_algorithm) which returns you the first topologic sorting in the lexicographic order, which has the advantage of being unique

Comment: FYI, Python 3.9 has a built in Topological Sorter: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/graphlib.html#module-graphlib